# Are these Transformations of the Green's function equivalent?

Tags: hamiltonian, greens-functions

The Green's function $G(E)$ can be constructed from the Hamiltonian $H$

$G(E) = [(E+i\epsilon)I - H]^{-1}$

where $I$ is the identity matrix. Say we want to perform a transformation into another basis set, with eigenbases $\{v_i\}$. E.g. We could transform the Hamiltonian like so: $V^\dagger H V$ where $V$ is the matrix of eigenbases.

My question: Does this hold?

$V^\dagger G(E)V = [(E+i\epsilon)I-V^\dagger HV]^{-1}$

Or do we have to do this instead

$V^\dagger G(E)V = V^\dagger[(E+i\epsilon)I- H]^{-1}V$

I.e. If we simply transform the Hamiltonian first, do we get the Green's function in the new basis? Or do we have to directly transform the Green's function first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $V^\dagger V=I$ then
$$
V^\dagger f(O)V = 
f(V^\dagger OV)
$$
This is proved by expanding $f(O)$ in Taylor series and *sandwiching* $VV^\dagger$ in $O^n$ products.